# How do birds fly forward (parallel to the earth)?

Tags: aerodynamics

What is the physics of a bird’s forward motion?

I know that a pressure difference in the air beneath their wings and above their wings can generate an upward force called lift. The velocity of air moving over their wings can contribute to this pressure difference.

But what I do not understand is... **what are the mechanics and physics of a bird’s forward motion, that takes them from one tree to another?**

How does a bird flapping its wings up and down generate forward motion? If gravity is a force perpendicular to the earth, then forward motion is parallel to the earth. It’s not obvious how flapping your wings up and down (perpendicular to the earth) makes a bird move forward (parallel to the earth).

What are the mechanics and physics of a bird flying forward (in the direction parallel to the earth)?

Comment: A bird wing is not a horizontal plane that moves up and down. Have you looked *at all* into the mechanics of bird flight? Wikipedia is a start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bird_flight . And https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4jKokxPRtck .

Answer (score 2):

A bird’s wing is very flexible. It does not simply flap up and down. On the downstroke, in particular, the bird can easily adjust how much air is pushed down and how much air is pushed backwards simply by making small adjustments in the angle of the feathers, especially the outermost flight feathers. As they angle ever so slightly upwards relative to the leading edge of the wing the air is pushed more backwards, providing a thrust force allowing the bird to overcome drag and accelerate.

Comment: (+1) Nice answer. It caused me to look up some of Leonardo da Vinci’s bird wing drawings.

Answer (score 1):

Understand the concept of a Lift Vector. It is not just UP, but it depends on the angle of the wing. When the wing moves down, it is angled to provide forward as well as vertical force. Same when it moves up.

Of course in an airplane with a propeller, the propeller just goes up and down. So how can it provide forward thrust? You can figure that out.